# How to search and select column names based on values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a pandas DataFrame like this

```
    name    col1    col2    col3 
0   AAA     1      0        2 
1   BBB     2      1        2 
2   CCC     0      0        2
```

I want (a) the names of any columns that contain a value of `2` *any*where in the column (i.e., `col1`, `col3`), and (b) the names of any columns that contain *only* values of `2` (i.e., `col3`).

I understand how to use `DataFrame.any()` and `DataFrame.all()` to select rows in a DataFrame where a value appears in any or all columns, but I'm trying to find COLUMNS where a value appears in (a) any or (b) all rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do what you described with columns:

```
df.columns[df.eq(2).any()]
# Index(['col1', 'col3'], dtype='object')

df.columns[df.eq(2).all()]
# Index(['col3'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the columns (a):

```
for column in df.columns:
  if (df[column]==2).any(axis=None)==True:
    print(column +"contains 2")
```

Here you get the name of the columns containing one or more 2.

(b) :

```
for column in df.columns:
  if (df[column]==2).all(axis=None)==True:
    print(column +"contains 2")
```